# Difference between various type of Variable declaration in swift

Tags: swift, ios9, variable-declaration

I am quite a confused when and how to declare variables in particular points in Swift and its causing a headache for a new guy like me in SWIFT.

What is the difference between the following type of declarations? I have given my thoughts and understanding on them. Please rectify me with your solution if I am wrong and be a bit explanatory so that I can know the actual and exact answer.

```
  Array - 
   1) var arr = NSArray()//I think its an instance of immutable NSArray type
   2) var arr = NSMutableArray()
   3) var arr = Array()//I have no idea of difference between NSArray and Array type. Might be both are same
   4) var arr : NSMutableArray?//Creates an optional type but how is it different from line no.2
   5) var arr : NSMutableArray = []//creates an empty array NSMutableArray type and again how is it different from line no.2 & 3
```

Please clarify a bit clearly so that my confusion level would be a bit clear. Thanks

Comment: Explain what you think they all are

Comment: @Wain I am editing my question with my views. Please rectify me and explain a bit. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array` is a swift type where as `NSArray` is an objective C type.  NS classes support dynamic-dispatch and technically are slightly slower to access than pure swift classes.

> 1) var arr = NSArray()

`arr` is an `NSArray()` here - you can re-assign things to `arr` but you can't change the contents of the `NSArray()` - this is a bad choice to use IMO because you've put an unusable array into the variable.  I really can't think of a reason you would want to make this call.

> 2) var arr = NSMutableArray()

Here you have something usable.  because the array is mutable you can add and remove items from it

> 3) var arr = Array()

**This won't compile** - but `var arr = Array<Int>()` will.

Array takes a generic element type ( as seen below)

```
public struct Array<Element> : CollectionType, MutableCollectionType, _DestructorSafeContainer {
    /// Always zero, which is the index of the first element when non-empty.
    public var startIndex: Int { get }
    /// A "past-the-end" element index; the successor of the last valid
    /// subscript argument.
    public var endIndex: Int { get }
    public subscript (index: Int) -> Element
    public subscript (subRange: Range<Int>) -> ArraySlice<Element>
}
```

> 4) var arr : NSMutableArray?

You are defining an **optional** array here.  This means that `arr` starts out with a value of `nil` and you an assign an array to it if you want later - or just keep it as nil.  The advantage here is that in your class/struct you won't actually have to set a value for `arr` in your initializer

> 5) var arr : NSMutableArray = []

[image]

It sounds like you are hung up on confusion about Optional values.

Optional means it *could* be *nil* or it *could not*

When you type something as `type?` that means it is `nil` unless you assign it something, and as such you have to **unwrap** it to access the values and work with it.

Comment: What is the difference between line no.3 & 4 & 5 ?

Comment: @user3441734 Why is it impossible. Swift says youy can have instance of aparticular type by adding '()' after the particular type.

Comment: @Array is generic container. The compiler must know which type of value you want to store there. var arr: Array<Int> = [] means I need a mutable storage (variable) which type is an array of integers and I ask the compiler to create an empty array as initial value of my variable

Comment: @user3441734 If you are saying that if I am declaring any array as var arr:Array<anyObject>=[] , it would be same as var arr  :  NSMutableArray = []. If you can give me anser based to my question it would be quite beneficial. So please give the answer with respect to my question when you are free.

Comment: What is the context?  This is really not that important stuff ... what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @Jeef So, just answer me at last the difference between no. 4 & 5.

Comment: Simple one is being initialized to an empty array and one is being set as optional (aka starting off as nil) (see picture)

Comment: #5 is the same as #2.  You are declaring a `NSMutableArray` and initializing it to an empty array.  The way you get there is different.  In #2, Swift infers the type of `arr` from the array being assigned to it.  In #5, you are explicitly declaring the type, so Swift then can infer what type of array to create when you say `[]`.

Comment: @G.Abhisek i updated the answer, however, you should play around in a playground some and it will help you see the differences.  Swift Playgrounds are very helpful for learning.

Comment: @G.Abhisek, when you are trying this in a Playground, OPTION-click on variables to see their types.

Comment: @Jeef, you still need to fix #3.  This one doesn't compile: `Generic parameter  'Element' could not be inferred`.

Comment: @vacawama - I'm only doing this because I'm bored.  Updated!

Answer (score 0):

@G.Abhisek at first about you question. `var arr: NSMutableArray = []` and `var arr = NSMutableArray()` means the same. the first one means, i ask the compiler to create a variable of type NSMutableArray and initialize it as an empty NSMutableArray. the second one means, i ask the compiler to create a variable and assign to it an empty initialized NSMutableArray. in the second case the compiler has to infer the right type of the variable, in the first case i did it by myself. still, the result will be the same.  `var arr1: Array<AnyObject> = []` and `var arr2: NSMutableArray = []` are totally different things!. arr1 srores value type Array, arr2 stores reference to the instance of an empty NSMutableArray class. you can write `let arr2: NSMutableArray = []` and next you can add an object there ... but you are not able to do thinks like `arr2 = ["a","b"]`. arr2 is constant, not variable, so the value stored there is imutable.

i am again close to my computer ... in the code below, you can see the main differences between swift and foundation arrays

```
import Foundation

let arr1: NSMutableArray = []
arr1.addObject("a")
arr1.addObject(10)
arr1.forEach {
    print($0, $0.dynamicType)
    /*
        a _NSContiguousString
        10 __NSCFNumber
    */
}

var arr2: Array<Any> = []
arr2.append("a")
arr2.append(10)
arr2.forEach {
    print($0, $0.dynamicType)
    /*
        a String
        10 Int
    */
}

var arr3: Array<AnyObject> = []
arr3.append("a")
arr3.append(10)
arr3.forEach {
    print($0, $0.dynamicType)
    /*
    a _NSContiguousString
    10 __NSCFNumber
    */
}

print(arr1.dynamicType, arr2.dynamicType, arr3.dynamicType)
// __NSArrayM Array<protocol<>> Array<AnyObject>
```

Comment: Can you say me how to declare an optional NSMutableArray-  var arr = NSMutableArray()? results in an error?